Can I publish my card game to the Google Play Store?
I have developed a card game. It is the Rung/Court Piece game popular in the subcontinent. It doesn't include or mention gambling in any way, made just for playing with friends online. Can I publish it to the Google Play Store? Would I be sinful?
